# jQuery Mobile Tabbar

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I m looking for a jQuery Mobile TabBar in iOS style that is "fixed" on the bottomarea of the screen like the nativ TabBar - Important is that it should be able to scroll the "content" div.

Also it should not be hidden if you scroll like here http://www.stokkers.mobi/valuables/bartender.html#landing

Comment: okay... return here if you've found it and you are having trouble

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use that plugin that you linked to http://www.stokkers.mobi/valuables/bartender.html#landing. Just use it with JQM 1.1-RC1 instead of the 1.0 beta that was used in that demo. JQM 1.1-RC1 introduced actual fixed toolbars to the library. Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/codaniel/2PGE7/1/) demonstrating the plugin with JQM 1.1-RC1.

Update. JQM 1.1.0 Final is now released.

Comment: Problem here is it disappeals if you scroll

Comment: No not if you are using JQM 1.1.0 final.

Comment: I m using that one

Uncompressed: jquery.mobile-1.1.0.js

And still it disappear... any demo

Comment: Yeah the jsfiddle in my answer.